# How do I access the BIOS on Kali Linux in order to change the username and password?

Tags: kali-linux, password-recovery

I just started using Kali, but I forgot what I used as password and username, so I want to know how change it. Can someone please help me?

Comment: If you just started using it, the easiest would be to re-install it and start again. Other than that, there exist several tutorials on how to reset the Kali password. Have you tried [any of those](http://www.technig.com/reset-lost-password-of-kali-linux/)?

Answer (score 0):

The OS you are using has nothing to do with how you access the BIOS. Often the keys you need to press are shown in a splash-screen before the actual system boots. (even before grub)

If they are not shown, try Delete, F2,F10,F11 or F12. If that doesn't work either, find out what mainboard/chipset you are using and break that into the search engine of your choice.

Comment: This will indeed get the user into the BIOS, but it does not solve the problem with the forgotten password.

Comment: he asked how to get into BIOS here goes the answer

Comment: The user asked the wrong question, so a helpful answer would point him to the solution to their real problem rather than providing something not helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with the command line?

Comment: No there is not. Kali-Linux (your Operation System) is not related to BIOS. The (U)EFI or BIOS is only relevant before the OS starts. You can only access it before the OS started, by the method described above. However as slhck stated correcly it will not help you reset your password.